# Parsing message into struct

Tags: c++, c, struct, casting

I am having a little bit of trouble parsing a message into a structure. I know that the message is broken into bytes, and that the message is always going to be 11 bytes long. I was told that a very elegant solution to parse the data is to just cast the incoming buffer into a struct of bytes. My question is how to perform that function. I heard that by casting the buffer as a char *, you should be able to perform the transformation in one or two lines.

```
typedef struct tStateMsg {
    uint8_t reportID;
    uint8_t ctrlName1;
    uint8_t State1;
    uint8_t ctrlName2;
    uint8_t State2;
    uint8_t ctrlName3;
    uint8_t State3;
    uint8_t ctrlName4;
    uint8_t State4;
    uint8_t ctrlName5;
    uint8_t State5;
} StateMsg;

void SetState(uint8 msgBuffer[], uint8 bufferSize) //BufferSize is always 11
{
    //Parse the message to the struct.
}
```

I know that there is additional error checking needed to ensure that the message is always 11 bytes long, and that all of the data I expect is present, but I am going to ignore that just for the time being.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I would be surprised if there was padding in here but do note that the compiler is allowed to add padding between the class members.  That means `sizeof(tStateMsg) >= 11 `

Comment: C or C++? They're not the same language. I'm fairly sure dbush's answer is illegal in C++. Tag one of them. Not both.

Comment: You'll want to look at [Eric Raymond's piece on structure packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/).

Comment: And no, @Asu, dbush's answer is not illegal in C++. It's perfectly legal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by casting the buffer (the address of the start of the buffer actually) to a pointer to the struct:

```
StateMsg *msg = (StateMsg *)msgBuffer;
```

Then you can reference the `struct` members.

One thing you need be careful about is alignment.  If the buffer was created by `malloc`, that buffer will be properly aligned for any data type.  If however the buffer is a local array, it might not be alligned on a boundary suitable for a `StateMsg`.

So be sure to use a malloc'ed buffer so address alignment issues.

As for padding between `struct` elements, the compiler is free to insert padding wherever it deems appropriate.  To be sure the struct is laid how you expect, you want to declare your `struct` as packed.  In gcc, you can do this with `#pragma packed`.

In practice however, as long as you put each element at the proper offset (i.e. 2 byte types at a 2 byte offset, 4 byte types at a 4 byte offset) you should end up with a structure that's laid out as you expect.  In your specific example, all of your fields are 1 byte so there shouldn't be any padding except at the end.

For more detail, take a look at [this excellent article on struct packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing) (Thanks to Rob K for bringing this up in the comments).

Comment: Be aware that the compiler is allowed to insert padding bytes between members, such as alignment.    In order to implement your solution, the stucture must be be packed.  Many compilers have *pragmas* or options to declare structures as packed.

Comment: In practice, for this struct, since it's all uint8_t, the compilers targeting 32 bit code will only add 1 byte at the end of the structure to bring it to 32 bit alignment, making the structure the size of 3 32-bit words OR if targeting 64 bit code, will add 5 bytes padding at the end of the structure to bring it to 64 bit alignment, making the structure the size of 2 64-bit words.(cf. http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_alignment_requirements).